# DataUrl to Bytearray in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I was trying to get the image from dataUrl in a jsp page as follow :

```
String dataUrl = request.getParameter("dataUrl");
String encodingPrefix = "base64,";
int contentStartIndex = dataUrl.indexOf(encodingPrefix) + encodingPrefix.length();
byte[] imageData = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(dataUrl.substring(contentStartIndex));

System.out.println(imageData);
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C://testimage.jpg");
fos.write(imageData);
```

But the problem am facing is that its giving an exception that :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: 26 in the jsp file: /uploadmyimage.jsp
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 cannot be resolved to a type
```

Please help to solve this problem.

[image: project]

Also my jsp having javascript from where am bringing dataUrl to this page is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#photo').photobooth().on("image", function (event, dataUrl) {
        alert(dataUrl);

        //alert(imgdata);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'uploadmyimage.jsp',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                encodeimg: dataUrl
            },
            error : function(){ 
                alert('Error'); 
            },
            success: function(msg){      
                    alert('Data updated.');                    
            }
        });

        $("#gallery").show().html('<img src="' + dataUrl + '" >');
        });
 });
```

But when i print this DataUrl in other called jsp.It does not print anything.

Comment: Did you bundle that jar in your deployment?

Comment: @LeosLiterak Yeah i did that.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Here is image of it : http://postimg.org/image/45imycysj/

Comment: Examine deployment - (exploded) war. Project structure does not need to be copied correctly.

Comment: for tomcat to find it at run time the jar has to be in `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: @LeosLiterak Iam working in netbeans so it itself take care of moving the file to WEB_INF/lib

Comment: @A4L I edited my post.Could you please see if am doing it right or not ?

Comment: @LeosLiterak I edited my post.Could you please CHECK ?

Comment: I do not know eclipse. Attach screen where you configure deployment artifacts. Codec library must be copied to WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Here is the pic : http://postimg.org/image/k5z0elybl/

Comment: It looks correctly. Could you post war so I can deploy it myself? There must be problem with bundled jar, though your setup looks fine.